# Get the actual value of a BoundField element in a gridview VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, gridview, selecteditem, selectedvalue, selectedindex

The following image depicts the full gridview I have:

[image]

I'm able to get the values of the second column (project_ID) in the back end as follows:

```
Dim val As String = grdProjects.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text.ToString
```

For instance if I press the *Select* of the third row I'll get back the value 3.
My problem appears when the gridview is updated and has less records as the one in the following image.

[image]

If I press the second record I get the value 2 instead of the value 4 that I'd like to get.

Any suggestions please on how to get the actual value of the cell instead of the number of the selected row?

Comment: Please show us the code in you code behind, how are you deleting rows from the gridview (it matters)?  Is the underlying data source updated as well?    Difficult to understand what is going on without the code.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but in VB.net datagrids SelectedRow does not exist, SelectedRows do exist.
Anyway, try this way and let me know if it work:

On the RowEnter or CellClick event use the E.RowIndex to get what you want. Do as follow:

```
Private Sub DataGrid1_RowEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGrid1.RowEnter
     Dim CellValue As String = DataGrid1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Project_ID").Value.ToString
End Sub
```

Notice that for the .cells() I use the name of the column, this is better because if in the future you add columns this code will not need to be changed. Easier code maintenance always pay! Also. Cell().Value instead Cell().Text

Nandostyle

Comment: You may want to delete this answer before you get hammered.  Not every grid is a DataGridView.  The OP is likely using [GridView Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx), but without proper tagging, inferences become common.

Comment: TnTinMn thanks for worrying about me. However, The question clearly state GridView and VB.net. Also, this is why I am asking him to try it, I guess that he would let me know that his grid is something else than a DataGridView. There is a GridView in ASP.net, if that is the case I have a solution for him too.

Comment: @Nandostyle I use an asp:GridView element, not a DataGridView.If you have any suggestions on how to get the cell value please let me know.

Comment: Try; GRDProjects.Rows(e.RowIndex).cells(Project_ID).Text